# How do I disassociate an Apple ID from my computer?

Tags: macos, apple-id

How do I disassociate an Apple ID from my device?

I have 2 Apple IDs: an old one that my laptop insists on using, and my new one that iTunes and my other devices use.

When trying to update software or download applications, my laptop insists on using the old Apple ID; how do I correct it?

Comment: You can use iTunes to unauthorized all devices.

Comment: I didn't see how to do it in iTunes.   Can you do a step by step guide, starting from the iTunes menu bar?   Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the Apple support article on this subject and deemed it as unhelpful?

Comment: I didn't find anything useful on Apple Support.   The answers address different questions.

Comment: So I take your last response as confirmation you have not unauthorized this device from the old apple id?

Comment: That sounds like a good thing to do.   Please don't assume that I understand the relationship between iCloud, AppleID, OSX, and iTunes, it's confusing to me why a music app should be involved in the process at all. How do I deauthorize the device (step by step instructions please)?

Comment: I have answered your question.  In the future please don't provide snarky responses, to those members, trying to understand where your confusion is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mean to offend.  It's certainly not your fault that this area is confusing, or that I feel frustrated trying to search through help guides that seem to be telling me all sorts of things that don't seem to be relevant, or to know what is in fact relevant.   I realise you are being helpful.   Can you post me a link to the instructions I need to follow?   Thanks for your assistance Ramhound.

Comment: Oops, I've just seen instructions lower down in the answers, I'll give them a try.

Comment: Okay tried them, see my problem description below, in the section with iTunes instructions.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have apps that were purchased under the Apple ID you want to stop using. App purchases *cannot* be transferred to a different Apple ID; they're permanently tied to the Apple ID they were purchased under. If you don't want to use that Apple ID anymore, you need to delete all of the apps purchased under that ID, then open the App store, sign into the new Apple ID you want to use (Store menu > Sign Out, then Store menu > Sign In), and re-download (and if necessary re-purchase) any that you still want to use.

Yes, this does mean that you'll need to pay for apps again. Sorry.

(Actually, there is one case where an app can be transferred between Apple IDs: if it was purchased via the volume purchase program using managed distribution. If you don't know what this is, you don't have it.)

Comment: I didn't purchase any apps with the old Apple ID.  I simply want my laptop to stop insisting on using the old apple ID.  When I try to buy apps from the app store, my old AppleID is pre-filled in to the purchase form.   If I change it to the new Apple ID, and carry on, I just get an error message.    My question is, how do I dissassociate my laptop from my old apple ID?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the portion of the Apple support article which explains how to deauthorized your machine.

> 1. Open iTunes.
> 2. Click Sign In, and then enter your Apple ID and password.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Click your name and select Account Info from the menu.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Enter your password again.
>
> On the Account Information screen:
>
> 1. Scroll to the Apple ID Summary section. To the right of Computer Authorizations, click Deauthorize All.
>
> [image]
>
> The Deauthorize All button appears only if you have more than 2
>   authorized computers. If you don't see the Deauthorize All button,
>   that means that you only have one authorized computer.
>
> **When you deauthorize all, you don't lose content**
>
> When you deauthorize a single computer, you don't lose content. The
>   same applies to if you choose to deauthorize all computers. You just
>   won't be able to access the content that you bought from iTunes on
>   those computers until you reauthorize them. You need to have the
>   computer to reauthorize it.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204385)

I suspect you also will need to know how to authorize your computer once you have cleared out the list of machines that are authorized.

> **How do I authorize a computer?**
>
> 1. If you don't have iTunes on the computer you want to authorize, [download and install the latest version.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201352)
> 2. Open iTunes.
> 3. Mac: From the menu bar at the top of your computer screen, choose Store > Authorize This Computer. Windows: Hold down the Control and B
>      keys on your keyboard to turn on the iTunes menu bar. Then choose
>      Store > Authorize This Computer. Learn more [about menus in iTunes for
>      Windows.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202662) In earlier versions of iTunes, you can access this option
>      from the Advanced menu.
>
> [image]
>
> If you're using iTunes in full-screen mode, hover your mouse at the
>   top of your computer screen. The menu bar appears. Exit full-screen
>   mode by pressing the Control, Command, and F keys on your keyboard.
>
> 4. Enter your [Apple ID](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/) and click Authorize.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201251)

To switch which account iTunes uses you would simply log out of the account then logged into the account you wish to use.  I don't believe a screenshot is required to explain how to do that.

Comment: is this legal ?

Comment: @Firee - Is what legal?  *I provided clear citation to everything I quoted.*  Please provide productive clear comments, vague comments like "is this legal", are not clear nor productive.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have the same version of itunes?  I have 12.2.2.25.  When I ope iTunes it does not appear give me a 'Sign In' button or menu option to click.   However if I click on the Store menu it gives me 'Deauthorize this computer' menu item.   When I click that it asks me for my AppleId and password, but shows my new AppleId pre-filled in.  I changed that to my old AppleId and entered the old password.  I receive an error message telling me that this computer was not authorized, and to authorize it I have to play a video or song that I purchesed

Comment: `Store->Sign Out` should also allow you to sign out then sign into the correct account you wish to use.  I am honestly confused at this point, at what point you are lost, signing into your AppleID isn't difficult.

Comment: I don't think my problem is with iTunes.   iTunes is happy to use my new AppleID only.   My problem is that I want to buy an application from App Store.

Comment: App Store wants me to log in using my Old AppleID (it is pre filled in).   I overtype the old AppleId with my new AppleId and enter the correct password, and it gives me the error "Unknown Error".   Somewhere my old AppleId is linked with either App Store, or my laptop; I want to disassociate the old AppleID from whichever AppStore/iCloud/Laptop it is linked with, and link it with my new AppleID in the hope that it will solve this problem and enable me to buy applications and update OSX.   I hope that this description makes sense.

Comment: @T1000 - Which AppStore are you talking about?  Apple AppStore ( OSX ) or AppStore on a iOS device?  You are not specific what your other devices are.

Comment: App Store OSX (laptop).